# When is the Legendre transformation not invertible?

Tags: legendre-transformation

I am wondering when the Legendre transformation is irreversible. I know if Y is a linear function of x, then the Legendre transformation of Y is irreversible. However ,what if Y is a multivariable function? Could anyone give necessary and sufficient conditions when Legendre transformation is invertible? Thanks!!

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230759/invertible-legendre-fenchel-transform-of-non-convex-function).